# How/where to convert dates from the server in a redux app?

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr, reselect

I'm starting to study redux now. I used the real-word example as a starting point, using normalizr and reselect to handle data.

Now, I need to understand where is the best place to convert dates coming from the server into js Date objects. Since normalizr already takes care of "some Schemas" I thought it could do that too, but I did not find it there.

Where should I convert these dates? My assumption is that I have to keep those dates already converted on the store. Is that right?

Comment: You don't have to, you can do the conversion in your presentational components as well if you wish.

Comment: Sure. But that would "couple" the view layer and the server format. I think that it's a better practice to convert it asap so that if I change the server later, the view will keep working. It seems to me that this is a responsibility of a "lower" layer. I'll paste my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizr can do this - in the current version (v3.3.0) you can achieve it like this:

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

const ReleaseSchema = new schema.Entity('releases', {}, {
  processStrategy: (obj, parent, key) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      createdAt: new Date(obj.createdAt),
      updatedAt: new Date(obj.updatedAt),
    };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a third parameter to callApi (inside api middleware):

```
function callApi(endpoint, schema, conversionFromServer) {
    const fullUrl = (endpoint.indexOf(API_ROOT) === -1) ? API_ROOT + endpoint : endpoint
    return fetch(fullUrl)
        .then(response =>
            response.json().then(json => ({ json, response }))
        ).then(({ json, response }) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(json)
            }
            const camelizedJson = camelizeKeys(json)
            const nextPageUrl = getNextPageUrl(response)
            let convJson = camelizedJson;
            if(conversionFromServer) {
                convJson = conversionFromServer(convJson);
            }
            return Object.assign({},
                normalize(convJson, schema),
                { nextPageUrl }
            )
        })
}
```

and now I can call it like this:

```
return {
    [CALL_API]: {
        types: [ TIMESLOTS_REQUEST, TIMESLOTS_SUCCESS, TIMESLOTS_FAILURE ],
        endpoint: `conference/${conferenceId}/timeslots`,
        schema: Schemas.TIMESLOT_ARRAY,
        conversionFromServer: (data) => {
            data.timeslots.forEach((t)=>{
                t.startTime=php2js.date(t.startTime)
                t.endTime=php2js.date(t.endTime)
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

This way I keep this conversion "as close to the server" as I can.